# Apply condition on groupby DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have this data:

[image: original data]

I applied pd.groupby function on it as the following:

[image: show the result here]

Now, I want to filter the above dataframe to give me the clients who has 2022 and hasn't 2023.

any one can help me please?

I didn't find any explain to this case

Comment: Which `groupby` function did you use? What was the original data? Do you have an index or columns?

Comment: I edit the question to answer, please see the images in the links

Comment: Please provide  input and desired output  in a copyable code or text format.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dic = {k: g['client'].tolist() for k, g in df.groupby('year')}
client_in_2023 = dic[2023]
client_in_2022 = dic[2022]
df_wo_2023 = df[~df['client'].isin(client_in_2023)]
df_in_2022 = df_wo_2023[df_wo_2023['client'].isin(client_in_2022)]

print(df)


client  year
0    co1  2021
1    co1  2022
2    co2  2021
3    co3  2022
4    co3  2023
5    co4  2023
6    co5  2022
print(df_in_2022)

    client  year
0    co1  2021
1    co1  2022
6    co5  2022
```